# implementing a recorder in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves playing, recording, and saving video to the SD card. I'm using the recorder class.

But the when I click the record button, the recording doesn't start.

Here is the code I tried:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
 ...
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
 recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/index.html)

Hope it can help you.

Do not forgot to set permission for recording audio

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
```